# Send Barcode string to an API endpoint

Tags: ios, swift, endpoint

I'm very new in programming. I have been learning Swift for a few months now. I'm trying to make an app that scans a 1D or 2D barcode, takes the string, and sends it to an API endpoint which will give me back some info. For example, product number and batch number.

For the barcode part I'm using really nice software from GitHub called BarcodeScanner. It is running without any issue and I'm able to get the string from the barcode it reads.

Once I have the string I'm able to send it to the API endpoint but then it gets stuck there.

If I run the same code in a playground it works without problems. It makes the request and I can see the answer in JSON from the server. If I run the code on the iPhone then it gets stuck. Of course I cannot use the scanning part when in playground. I use it to test the networking part and communication with the API.

Here is my Networking.swift file. It has some `print()` used for debug:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol NetworkManagerDelegate: class {
    func didUpdatePharmo(pharmo: PharmoModel)
    func didUpdateBarcode(barcode: BarcodeModel)
}

public struct NetworkManager {
    var delegate: NetworkManagerDelegate?
    
    let pharmoURL = "https://someurl.com/api"
    
    let pharmoEndpoint = "https://someendpoint.com/api"
     
    func fetchData(productNumber: String) {
        let urlString = "\(pharmoURL)&number=\(productNumber)"
        performRequestProductInfo(urlString: urlString)
        print(urlString)
    }
    
    func fetchEndpoint(dataMatrix: String) {
        let urlString = "\(pharmoEndpoint)&datamatrix=\(dataMatrix)"
        performRequestEndpoint(urlString: urlString)
        print(urlString)   
    }
    
    func performRequestEndpoint(urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("EndPoint HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)")
                    
                }
                
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let barcode = self.parseJSONEndpoint(endPointData: safeData) {
                        self.delegate?.didUpdateBarcode(barcode: barcode)
                   }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSONEndpoint(endPointData: Data) -> BarcodeModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(BarcodeData.self, from: endPointData)
            let productNumber = decodedData.product_number
            let batchNumber = decodedData.batchnumber
            
            let barcode = BarcodeModel(productNumber: productNumber, batchNumber: batchNumber)
            
            print(batchNumber)
            
            return barcode
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func performRequestProductInfo(urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                  print("ProductInfo HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)")
                }
                
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let pharmo = self.parseJSONProductInfo(pharmoData: safeData) {
                        self.delegate?.didUpdatePharmo(pharmo: pharmo)
                       
                   }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSONProductInfo(pharmoData: Data) -> PharmoModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(PharmoData.self, from: pharmoData)
            let id = decodedData.id
            let number = decodedData.number
            let name = decodedData.name
            let atcCode = decodedData.atc_code
            let imagePath = decodedData.image_path
            let displayImage = decodedData.display_image
            let storageGroupId = decodedData.storage_group_id
            let animalGroupId = decodedData.animal_group_id
            let udlevbest = decodedData.udlevbest
            let packageSizeText = decodedData.package_size_text
            let packageSizeNum = decodedData.package_size_num
            let unitCode = decodedData.unit_code
            let strengthText = decodedData.strength_text
            let prodPrice = decodedData.prod_price
            let aupPrice = decodedData.aup_price
            let aupInstPrice = decodedData.aup_inst_price
            let animalGroups = decodedData.animal_groups
            let udleveringsbestemmelse = decodedData.udleveringsbestemmelse
            let animalGroup = decodedData.animal_group
            let storageGroup = decodedData.storage_group
            let species = decodedData.species
            let indications = decodedData.indications
            let substances = decodedData.substances
            let manufacturer = decodedData.manufacturer
            
            let pharmo = PharmoModel(id: id, number: number, name: name, atc_code: atcCode, image_path: imagePath, display_image: displayImage, storage_group_id: storageGroupId, animal_group_id: animalGroupId, udlevbest: udlevbest, package_size_text: packageSizeText, package_size_num: packageSizeNum, unit_code: unitCode, strength_text: strengthText, prod_price: prodPrice, aup_price: aupPrice, aup_inst_price: aupInstPrice, animal_groups: animalGroups, udleveringsbestemmelse: udleveringsbestemmelse, animal_group: animalGroup, storage_group: storageGroup, species: species, indications: indications, substances: substances, manufacturer: manufacturer)
            
            print(name)
            
            return pharmo
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

From the ViewController.swift running the barcode scanner I call the function `fetchEndpoint(dataMatrix: String)`.

```swift
extension ViewController: BarcodeScannerCodeDelegate {
    func scanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController, didCaptureCode code: String, type: String) {
        print("Barcode Data: \(code)")
        print("Symbology Type: \(type)")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            networkManager.fetchEndpoint(dataMatrix: code)
        }
    }
}
```

From the console output I can see these two `print()` statements from ViewController.swift:

```
print("Barcode Data: \(code)")
print("Symbology Type: \(type)")
```

I can also see this `print()` statement from Networking.swift:

```
print(urlString)
```

But nothing happens after that. Again if I run the same code in a playground it works fine. I have also made requests using Postman, so I can see the JSON file and be sure the urlstring is working.

Anyone have some idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set breakpoints and single step through.  For example, if the first `if let` fails in `performRequestEndpoint` then no work is done and nothing more is output.  Swift style favours closures over delegation pattern, but you can use a delegate.  You seem to have a lot of code to create the `PharmoModel` when `Codable` will just do that for you.  You can use `CodingKeys` to map between JSON property names and Swift property names.  It is also better & safer to use `URLComponents` rather than string interpolation to create `URL`s

Comment: Thnaks for your comment. I do have a Codable structure for parsing the JSON received as an answer from the server. Once I have parsed it I create the model. Probably it is not the best way. I'll take a look at URLComponents, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the problem. The string being read from the scanner had an non ASCII character.

At any point XCode said anything about a non ASCII character, I had to copy the string into a playground, then I received this error:

```
Unprintable ASCII character found in source file
```

I copied the string into a terminal shell and I was able to see the character.

```
datamatrix=^]01036611030467831722113010RXT0711GC
```

I will try to use `URLComponents` or `percent encoding`

Comment: you should mark this answer as the solution by clicking on the checkmark below the vote buttons :)